# How do I block ads on YouTube in all WebKit based browsers?

Tags: browser, youtube, ads

How do I block ads on youtube on my android device? I have tried proxy websites - hide.me and plenty others, however, they work only on a windows machine, on android, they don't work, the webpage says "javascript not enabled". I have tried ad blocking proxy apps- adblock(no root), SEVEN adclear(non play store and play store versions), Adguard(non play store and play store versions). but it seems like youTube has found a way to bypass them all. IS this possible on android? if yes, how do i make it work?

PS: Or is there any free vpn app (not free trial) which blocks ads. I want this to work on all webKit (webView) based browsers

Comment: you want to block ads on YouTube Mobile app or from Mobile browser playing videos from www.youtube.com??

Comment: "I want this to work on all webKit (webView) based browsers" of course i want it to work on browsers, not the YouTube app.

Comment: There are some XPOSED plugins

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to block ads in the Youtube APP as long as you don't want to root your device. Blocking these ads requires changes to the DNS settings and you can't change these settings without root, nor can an app.

When you don't want to root your device the only option I see is just to use Firefox (or a similar Browser), install the Adblocker addon and watch your videos through the browser. Less comfort, but the only option remaining without root.

Answer (score 1):

If you have root you can use adaway app. It's completely free and 100% working. You can download it here https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.adaway . This app blocks all ads in browsers, all apps and games and youtube too, it uses hosts file to do so.

Comment: Note that this app requires root.